# Laravel get every date value for every user

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get value for every date even there is no transaction:

```
$transaction = Transaction::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), ['2015-12-01', '2016-12-31'])
                ->where('vendor_id', $row)
                ->groupBy('vendor_id', DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
                ->selectRaw('FLOOR(SUM(amount)) as total, DATE(created_at) as date')
                ->orderBy('created_at')->get();

return $transaction;
```

The result I get:

```
[{"total":"81739","date":"2015-12-22"},{"total":"82912","date":"2015-12-26"},{"total":"55912","date":"2015-12-27"},{"total":"55599","date":"2015-12-30"},{"total":"77626","date":"2015-12-31"}];
```

How can I get value for every date if it's no value insert it with 0?.

Thanks.

Comment: Try by removing the groupBy statement.

Comment: if remove the groupby statement it will become 1 value. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: added new solution (without joining)

The idea is very simple: if you've no transactions today, today's date is not in your transaction table.

**The solution is simple too: you've to store every date like so:**

Run every day at 00:00:00 a cronjob that inserts an empty transaction. So you get every date in your transaction table without joining to another table.

Be care: only if there's a 'real' transaction for a date, the 'fake' (empty) transaction should be deleted.

**Alternative 1**:

- Create a table with dates  (with `id` and `date`), for example from 2015-01-01 to 2025-12-31
- Select your dates and left join to the transaction table

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM dates d LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.date_id = d.id
```

Instead of storing the date in your transaction table, your store the foreign key to the dates table.

**Alternative 2:**

- Create a table for dates (with `id` and `date`)
- Run every 00:00:00 a cronjob that insert the current date
- Select your dates and left join to the transaction table

**Alternative 3:**

- Generate with php's DateInterval a date range
- Link the records from your transaction table to every right date of the range

Comment: you mean to make `tmp table`. so everytime i query insert to it and get the value ?

Comment: To solve the 'holes' in the date range: store the dates in a date table, that you fill. Personally, I prefer alternative 1. Every day 00:00:00 your insert today's date. You selects the wanted period from your dates table and left join to the transaction table. So you get every date in that period, and get the transaction if exist.

Comment: if I add like that it will going to be a lot. I have like 2000 vendor, and every transaction i need `user_id` which is foreign key to users table. But I will consider this approach and try it to see the result. And transaction column type for created_at is datetime. I need the time for another query

Comment: I understand. I changed my answer with a solution without joins.

Comment: alright. will try 3 one first. and will see if its work or not.

Comment: Hi, I use 3rd one and it working perfectly. I foreach the date range. My question is if user select 1 year, will it slow down the query, because i need to sum the transaction for each day?

Comment: Nice! I think you can SUM the transaction in the query, so in the foreach the summed value is available.